# A room serving the role of a tiny hospital

Tags: phrase-request

What is the name of an entity - a room or a couple rooms, or a small detached building serving the role of a tiny hospital within a larger entity (military base, prison, or even a ship.) Essentially, a place where the sick of the enclosed entity are treated, either for milder cases where actual hospital is not necessary, or when access to a real hospital is unavailable.

Comment: That sounds like a *sick bay* to me, especially for ships. Another word that might be more generic, but I'm not sure about being one or two rooms, is a *ward*.

Comment: I thought *sick bay* was reserved to the military & ships? In a boarding school it is *an infirmary*. There are *first aid rooms* (or *units*) in workplaces. The word might well vary according to the place...

Comment: @Laure: It is quite possible English has different words for different forms of that kind of entity - in my language one word covers mostly all of them.

Comment: And it might be different in UK, USA, Australia, ...

Comment: In places like schools and large businesses in the US you might just call it "The Nurse's Office"

Comment: Interesting thing when trying to use Google Translate, to Polish - "Sick bay" = "chore zatoki" = "sick sinuses". Thing is "zatoka" means "bay" in the geographic meaning, and "sinus" in the medical meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aboard a ship, it is called a **sickbay**. Considering the definitions of it here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sickbay?q=sickbay and here http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sickbay, this might also be suitable to use when talking about such a room in general, even when it is on land.

According to this link http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/infirmary, the word **infirmary** can used be used in general but, it does not include ships.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for "infirmary". Also possible are "clinic" or, as Jim says, "nurse's office".